# Verificar retorno de consulta PDO para deletar ou inserir registros

Tags: php, pdo

Estou fazendo um select para `deletar` ou `inserir` registros em meu `bd` de acordo com a quantidade de registros retornados, mas os testes que tenho feito não estão corretos, não sei exatamente como contar os registros em um retorno `pdo`.
Já usei o `count` e não funcionou, creio estar errando muito na elaboração de minha tentativa.

Vou postar o código comentado para ajudar na compreensão, o código é esse:

```
// VERIFICANDO DIREITOS 
$sqlInterface = "    
    SELECT 
      gasUsuarioServico.IdUsuario,
      gasUsuarioServico.IdServico,
      gasServico.IdInterface
    FROM
      gasUsuarioServico
      INNER JOIN gasServico ON (gasUsuarioServico.IdServico = gasServico.IdServico)
    WHERE
      (gasUsuarioServico.IdUsuario = ?) AND 
      (gasServico.IdInterface = ?)";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sqlInterface);
// DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL PDO::PARAM_INT OU STR
$stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->execute();    
$registros = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
// TENTATIVA DE CONTAGEM DE REGISTROS RETORNADOS
$conSqlDel = count($registros);    

if( $conSqlDel == 0 ){

    $sqlDel = "DELETE FROM gasUsuarioInterface WHERE gasUsuarioInterface.IdUsuario = ? AND gasUsuarioInterface.IdInterface = ?";
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sqlDel);        
    $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);                    
    $retorno = $stm->execute();  

} else {

    $sqlInterfaceReg = "    
        SELECT *
        FROM
            gasUsuarioInterface
        WHERE
            (gasUsuarioInterface.IdUsuario = ?) AND 
            (gasUsuarioInterface.IdInterface = ?)";
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sqlInterfaceReg);
    // DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL PDO::PARAM_INT OU STR
    $stm->bindValue(1, $IdUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->bindValue(2, $IdInterface, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();        
    $registros = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $countInsert = count($registros);

    if ($countInsert == 0) {            
        $arrayDados = array('IdUsuario' => $IdUsuario, 'IdServico' => $IdInterface );              
        $retorno = $crud->insert($arrayDados);   
    }    
}
```

No teste que fiz a variável $conSqlDel retorno 2 registros, mas no meu bd o valor é zero, ou seja, nenhum registro retornado.

Estou enviando um retorno JSON, dessa forma:

```
    // MENSAGEM AO USUÁRIO
if ($retorno):
    $retorno = array('codigo' => 1, 'mensagem' =>  print_r($conSqlDel) );
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
else:
    $retorno = array('codigo' => '0', 'mensagem' => ' Registro não foi atualizado' );
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
endif;
```

Não sei como verificar o conteúdo das variáveis, sendo que um simples `echo` ou `print_r` não funciona.

Comment: de um var_dump no $conSqlDel e mostre-nos o resultado

Comment: Parece estar certo, se der um foreach no resultado do select (que deu o count 2 e vc fala que deveria ser 0) mostra algo?

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss, eu já fiz esse teste, mas com select ele não funcionou, deu um erro de chamada de função, com insert, update e delete foi tranquilo, mas com o select não.

Comment: sim, o rowCount também é uma alternativa, mas não é garantido. De acordo com a documentação, em alguns bancos de dados ele pode não funcionar, então o mais recomendável é a forma em que está sendo feita.

Comment: sim @adventistapr, ele retorna o rows affected do último comando executado. Porém, há este problema com alguns banco de dados como citei.

Comment: vc está dando json_encode na variável errada, coloque $conSqlDel;